# Javalin hangs when asked to give 1XX HTTP status

Tags: java, http-status-codes, javalin

I have a Javalin server, the relevant code called by the endpoint looks like this:

```
...
if(!someFuture.isDone()){
    ctx.status(102);
    return;
}
```

Javalin hangs and does not return anything* when the HTTP status is set to anything in the `1XX` range. `2XX`, `3XX` and `4XX` are returned without any problems. I haven't been able to find anything in Javalin's documentation about this, but are `1XX` status codes not allowed by Javalin? If not, why is `102` causing this problem?

*eventually Postman registers a socket hang up

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of the 1XX range is:

> The server has received the request and is continuing the process

So when you respond with it, the client will await data.

From [the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html) (`Javalin` builded on `Jetty`):

> 102 Processing RFC 2518 defined the 102 Processing status code that
> can be sent:
>
> when the server has a reasonable expectation that the request will
> take significant time to complete. As guidance, if a method is taking
> longer than 20 seconds (a reasonable, but arbitrary value) to process
> the server SHOULD return a 102 Processing response. — RFC 2518 section
> 10.1 However, a later update of RFC 2518, RFC 4918, removed the 102 Processing status code for "lack of implementation".
>
> Jetty supports the 102 Processing status code. If a request is
> received with the Expect: 102-processing header, then a filter/servlet
> may send a 102 Processing response (without terminating further
> processing) by calling response.sendError(102).